# Italian word for "receptionist"

Tags: translation

Is there a purely Italian word for "receptionist"?

I looked into online dictionaries and only found: "addetto alla *reception*".

Comment: You could also refer to a receptionist as _addetto al ricevimento_ o _addetto alla ricezione_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't remind right now a single Italian term to translate "receptionist" but you could certainly refer to him using **addetto al ricevimento** o **addetto alla ricezione**.

[Garzanti](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=receptionist) also indicates this entry:

> addetto (m.; f. -a) all’accettazione (di albergo, ospedale ecc.).

In some cases the term or expression could change depending on the context you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, "accettazione" is a good translation for "reception". I would exclude "ricevimento" which mostly means "party". Also "ricezione" mostly sounds like "catching" (as in baseball).

Answer (score -1):

I would like to say that today Italian uses a lot of English words if they came abroad without the translation itself. It means that you can easy leave "il/la receptionist" and it will be no mistake or problem, **moreover it will be most correctly to use**.

The answer is easy: the word "reception" came from English to all the languages and used as it is.

But if you want to translate in the meaning, the nearest idea will be "secretary" o "segretario/a" in Italian.

Comment: Non sono io a dare il voto negativo, ma penso che il problema sia che l'OP chiede "a purely Italian word". Poi, a me sembra che, in genere, "segretario/a" non abbia sempre il significato del concetto espresso nella domanda.